# ReactJS onClick ReactCSSTransitionGroup animation

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am new to react and react animations. So with "appear" animations on page load everything is working. But now I have an issue. When I click the nav I want the new div to not just show up instantly, but fade in slowly (or any other animation for that mather), but it does not work.

TLDR; onClick event does not make the animation it just set's a new class.

Also maybe anybody knows how to enable ReactCSSTransitionGroup to work only when I scrool down to a sertain part of the website? Thank You!

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from "react-addons-css-transition-group";

export default class Nav extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        navStatus: "navHide"
    };
}

navClose(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({
        navStatus: "navHide",
        navLines: "navLines show"
    });
}

navOpen() {
    this.setState({
        navStatus: "navShow",
        navLines: "navLines hide"
    });
}


render() {
    return(
        <nav>
            <div className={this.state.navLines} onClick={this.navOpen.bind(this)}>
            </div>
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="navShow" transitionAppear={true} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
            <div id="myNav" className={this.state.navStatus}>
                <div className="navClose" onClick={this.navClose.bind(this)}>
                    <img className="navCloseBtn" src="svg/close.svg"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Too many `bind(..)` calls. Remove the `this.fn = this.fn.bind(this)` statements. These are unattractive and unnecessary. You're also calling `this.navClose.bind(this)` in your onClick handler, which makes me wonder why you made the aliases in the first place...

Comment: Sure think. I have removed it, looks like it does not have any purpose. Anyhow maybe You call help me out with the ReactCssTransitionGroup?

Comment: see my answer below. I've worked with ReactCSSTransitionGroups often and can answer many questions that you may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove the state handling the CSS class. It's best to decouple css-selectors from your React component state. There's a better way to manage state-derived css-selectors

Do something along these lines. It's a common pattern that I've used within my FE, React codebases across multiple projects. It's easy to maintain and uses pure JS to manage BEM selector creation.

```
render() {
  const { isOpen } = this.state;

  const classnames = [
    'nav',
    isOpen && 'nav--open'
  ].filter(Boolean);

  return (
    <nav className={classnames.join(' ')}>
      ...
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Now let's talk about ReactCSSTransitionGroup. Use this add-on when you're trying to add animations hooked into DOM elements mounting and unmounting from the DOM tree. If the element isn't leaving the DOM tree, then handling your animations with css-selectors being dynamically applied like the above code snippet.

Don't just use ReactCSSTransitionGroups whenever you need to animate something in React; this is over-engineering.

Set a transition property on the parent-most selector that you're interested in animating. Something like this...

```
.nav {
  ...
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Now add the following CSS to the dynamically applied CSS-selectors (i.e. state-derived CSS-selectors).

```
.nav--open {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is a [link to a simple, Vanilla JS example](http://jsbin.com/dobara/edit?html,css,js,output) of what applying CSS-selectors can do for your animations.

Here is a [link to an example](http://jsbin.com/juxeve/edit?css,js,output) using React and basic CSS transitions.

Here is a [link to another example](http://jsbin.com/pilina/edit?css,js,output) using React and CSSTransitionGroup, where the DOM element is mounting and dismounting from the DOM.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you'd like an example of putting this altogether, let me know, and I can create a simple React example.

Comment: If that's not to much to ask, then that would be awesome!

Comment: @xoomer http://jsbin.com/juxeve/edit?css,js,output here's an example without ReactCSSTransitionGroup. NOTE: it does not remove the nav from the page. I'll attach a version that removes it from the DOM.

Comment: @xoomer here is another example using CSSTransitionGroup where the DOM element removes itself from the DOM Tree. http://jsbin.com/pilina/edit?css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You should remove child of `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` in the onClick handler. Something like this should work:

```
navClose(e) {
  this.setState({visible: false});
},

navOpen(e) {
  this.setState({visible: true});
}


render() {
  return(
      <nav>
        <div className={this.state.navLines} onClick={this.navOpen.bind(this)}>
        </div>
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="navShow" transitionAppear={true} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
        { this.state.visible &&
          <div id="myNav" className={this.state.navStatus}>
            <div className="navClose" onClick={this.navClose.bind(this)}>
                <img className="navCloseBtn" src="svg/close.svg"></img>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </nav>
  );
}
```